# Running docker as sudo

Tags: macos, sudo, docker

I installed boot2docker and I ran:

```
./boot2docker start
 export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:4243
```

I started a tutorial from the Docker site.

I don't understand one thing - when I run:

```
sudo docker info
==>
Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.11/info: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory
```

However when I run without `sudo` it works:

```
MacCris:bin cristianc$ docker info
Containers: 2
Images: 10
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs
 Dirs: 14
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Kernel Version: 3.14.1-tinycore64
Debug mode (server): true
Debug mode (client): false
```

Any idea why running with sudo as in the tutorial does not work (at least for me)?

Comment: This is because using sudo is clearing out your env. There is no need to use sudo here because you are connecting over the TCP interface

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable isn't set.  You can confirm this by doing:

```
> env
```

Then as sudo:

```
> sudo env
```

Without the `DOCKER_HOST` variable set, docker can't connect to the daemon.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
sudo DOCKER_HOST=$DOCKER_HOST docker run
```

This way the required environment variable will be available with `sudo`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the `DOCKER_HOST` variable from your profile to be available when you run docker command with sudo, then you can add the following line to `sudoers` file. Open with:

```
sudo visudo
```

Add:

```
Defaults        env_keep += "DOCKER_HOST"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using boot2docker, then go to `/Application` folder and run the command

```
$(boot2docker shellinit)
```

It will fix your `DOCKER_HOST` variable in environment.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the environment variable `DOCKER_HOST` to `tcp://192.168.59.103:2375` works for me.

Quickest way would be running this in your command line (for OSX/Unix/Linux machines):

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2375
```